# htaccess redirect to custom address instead of showing Forbidden error message

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have folder with images in root directory and I need deny to access that images from URL.

I have `.htaccess` in this folder

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s?)://(www\.)?localhost.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ - [F]
```

This works perfect and if try to access image via URL, it shows error

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access ..

But I want instead, redirect to my custom error page (which is `/error` controller in my case).

What is correct `.htaccess` syntax for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

specify

```
   ErrorDocument 403 /error
```

after line `RewriteEngine on`

so it will be like this :

```
RewriteEngine on 
ErrorDocument 403 /error
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s?)://(www\.)?localhost.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ - [F]
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/forbid.html
```

Have a look at this link http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess2.shtml

I'm not sure that it would work with a route, maybe you have to specify a document.
I'd try it though.